# FlexPad library for Flex is running slow on iPad

Tags: ipad, apache-flex, mobile, flexbuilder

I've got a test mobile project app in Flex composed simply of a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication with two tabs - on one tab I have nothing and on the other I have a flexpad:List with an inline ArrayCollection just for testing - I have about 50 items in the list with just a label. It takes a long time to load the tab with this list on it and scrolling the list is really slow and jumpy. With so little in this app to start i'm thinking i'm probably doing something very wrong to get this really aweful performance. Any clues what to do? I'm using the latest AIR, Flex SDK 4.6, all systems are up to date.

Here is the Tab that seems slow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:flexpad="http://code.google.com/p/flexpad/" title="Tab 2">
    <flexpad:List width="300" height="200">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label One"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Two"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Three"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Four"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object label="Label Five"></fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </flexpad:List>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Which version of the iPad are you running?  What is FlexPad?  Did you create a release build (faster), or are you using a debug build (slower)?  If you share some code, perhaps we can provide some optimizing advice.

Comment: FlexPad is a flex component library: http://code.google.com/p/flexpad/

Comment: My version on the ipad is 5.1.1 and I did select the "fast" mode in the run configuration settings

Comment: "fast" is the wrong mode. You need the "slow" compilation mode, which  comes close to a release build. More compilation time == more efficient code == more performance on the device. If you really want to test the performance on your device, make a proper release build though.